Pattern for the positive set of a function in TiKZ
I am started to create a graph similar to the one shown in the figure drawing the set where the function (for example this \frac{x^{2}}{1-x^{2}}) highlighting where it is positive or negative.

You can see that in my MWE the filldraw option hidden the axes, dots, etc. In addendum the pattern library doesn't provide more widely spaced diagonal lines in gray. In my opinion, it's difficult to look at the drawing with this pattern that is very ugly.
Here there is a draft of my MWE.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
Here I want use a defalut font.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\draw [->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node [left] {$y$};
\draw [fill=white] (1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=white] (-1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw (1,0) node [above right] {$1$};
\draw (-1,0) node [above left] {$-1$};
\draw [dashed](1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5);
\draw [dashed](-1,-1.5) -- (-1,1.5);
%\draw [thick, domain=-0.5:-2] plot (\x,{plot the function \frac{x^{2}}{1-x^{2}}});
\filldraw [pattern=north east lines, draw=white] (-1,1.5) -- (-1,-1.5) -- (1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5);
%\filldraw [fill=lightgray, draw=white] (-1,1.5) -- (-1,-1.5) -- (1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Bla bla bla.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



not sure if this is what you're asking, but with the new patterns code you can configure the pattern e.g. to change the distance between the lines etc. so if the problem is that the old patterns are too inflexible, have a look at the newer ones instead.

Hi Sebastiano! Bentornato!

@Rmano Happy to see you again. Thank you so much for your invaluable contribution!

@cfr I vaguely remembered something. You're right. I've now modified the question, hoping it's clearer. I have read also your guide of BaskervaldADF. I have seen that Baskervald ADF is a serif family.

@Sebastiano note there are two versions of BaskervaldADF in TeX: baskervaldx is different from baskervald :-). if you read something I wrote, it concerns baskervald and not baskervaldx.

You can try this to draw the pattern:
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=gray!50] (-1,1.5) -- (-1,-1.5) -- (1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5);
\end{scope}


Also, probably, draw the white dots after the dashed line, so that the fill covers them.
To also answer to the font question you asked in chat, here is a possibility (thanks @Ulrike...)


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,backgrounds}
%% this will redefine the sans serif font to be Oswald
\usepackage{Oswald}

\begin{document}
Here I want to use a default font.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    {% set the font to sans-serif
    \sffamily
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
        % Notice that if you use math, the font will switch to
        % the standard one, Oswald doesn't do math...
        \draw [->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node [below] {x};
        \draw [->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node [left] {y};
        \draw (1,0) node [above right] {1};
        \draw (-1,0) node [above left] {-1};
        \draw [dashed](1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5);
        \draw [dashed](-1,-1.5) -- (-1,1.5);
        \draw [fill=white] (1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
        \draw [fill=white] (-1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \fill[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=gray!50] (-1,1.5) -- (-1,-1.5) -- (1,-1.5) -- (1,1.5);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    } %close font switch
    \caption{Bla bla bla.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



Dear Rmano, I have improved the content of the question: specifically, please read points 1), 4), and (!). I have seen that Baskervald ADF is a serif family (\ssfamily). I have also attached two additional figures for clarity. Always infinitely grateful.

I am not sure I understand: do you want to use the baskervald only for diagram and not for the text? Why? It's not better to use (if you like it) newtx for everything and be happy?

Dear Rmano, I'm always in a hurry. I'm making slides with Beamer and I use sansmathfont. One day I'll use the newtx package and baskervaldx for the images. If you want, I can add the packages for you. Yes: I want baskervald only for the diagrams and not for the text. I like the combination .

Ah, ok, maybe I get it: you want Computer Modern for the main text and math and locally switching to Baskervald for diagrams text and math. Is like this? I do not know if/how this is possible in pdflatex; maybe you'd need to switch to lualatex for this. But I think that the problem with this question is that there are too many subquestions here --- it would have been better to have on question for the dash pattern, and another one to switch fonts locally.
